# Probabilities that a student will pass different tests (probabilty for each test)

Tags: probability

1. A student takes test with multiple variants (A, B, C, D) always picking up A.
   There is only one correct answer and there is no pattern thus the answers are randomly placed. There are 100 questions.

As I understand, the chance that the student will answer all 100 questions correctly is (1/4)^100.

**Q:** What is the chance of the student getting:

a) 50 correct answers;

b) 75 correct answers;

c) 90 correct answers;

d) 0 correct answers (i feel like this one is (3/4)^100 but i'm not sure);

***and how did you calculate each chance?***

2. A student takes true/false test always picking up true.
   There is no pattern thus the answers are randomly placed. There are 100 questions.

As I understand, the chance that he will answer all 100 questions correctly is (1/2)^100.

**Q:** What is the chance that he will answer 50 questions correctly?

I feel like the chance is 50% but i don't have any calculations for this.

Comment: These questions all concern standard properties of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  Reading up on that should answer all your questions.

Comment: The chance of $a$ correct answers and $100-a$ wrong answers is given by the formula $$\binom{100}{a} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^a \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{100-a}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint -

You can use binomial distribution -

$p(Correct) = \frac14$

$q(Incorrect) = 1 - \frac 14 = \frac34$

Now according to bionamial distribution.

$P(X=r) = \binom nr × (q)^{n-r} × (p)^r$

a.) Here X = 50 and n = 100.

b.) Here X = 75 and n = 100.

You can similarly do other parts.

Comment: i've used a calculator (of binomial distribution) to get the answers.
couldn't really do it part by part because 50!*50! isn't really the best stuff to calculate.
i would really appreciate step by step guide onto solving, let's say, 1a.
i'm not really good at math, reading on the topic of binomial distribution for person who is like 2 hours into this and barely managed his school math classes is pretty difficult :)

Comment: Your question involves lots of calculations. And its not possible to solve without calculator. So you can simply put values and leave it as it is.